# Prove that $G$ is abelian and has odd order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be a finite group and suppose that there an automorphism $f$ of $G$ satisfying: $f^2 =id_G$ and $f(x)=x \iff x =1$. Show that every element of $G$ can be written as $f(x)x^{-1}$ for some $x$ and that $G$ is abelian of odd order.

The first part I know how to do. Define $s: G \to G$ by $s(g) = f(g)g^{-1}$. Then $s$ is one-one because $s(g)=s(g') \implies f(gg'^{-1}) = gg'^{-1} \implies gg'^{-1} = 1 \implies g = g'$. So since $G$ is finite $s$ is onto so every element can be written as $f(x)x^{-1}$.

How to show that $G$ is abelian and has odd order?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Sorry, I apparently made a little mistake in my argument.

Comment: Derek Holt it isn't *exactly* a duplicate.. I still need to prove it has an odd order.

Comment: Yes that's right. But the fact that $G$ has odd order follows immediately from the assumptions. It is easier to prove that than it is to prove that $G$ is abelian.

Comment: sets like $\{x,f(x)\}$ for $x\neq1$ and $\{1\}$ form a partition. That declares oddness of order.

Comment: @DerekHolt just sayin'..